# Magento Custom Search Extension (external source) - sorting by relevance

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I am currently building a fuzzy search extension for magento that gets its results from an external server.

The problem I am having is that after combining the external search results with the results from the Magento database select, I can't find a solution to sort/order the products in the collection object based on relevance values from an xml file. 
If anyone could help me with this I would be very pleased =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am currently building a fuzzy search extension for magento that gets
>   its results from an external server.

You can look a bit more into this, because Magento search using **Solr** or **Elasticsearch** does the same thing...

How Magento search works:

- user inputs a search query
- magento looks if there is a stored search result for that query (database tables: `catalogsearch_query` and `catalogsearch_result`)
- if nothing is found, it performs the search query based on configuration (like, fulltext, solr, whatever is set for this)
- stores the result ids and sort order in the proper tables (hint: `catalogsearch_result`); here you can find the relevance field
- gets the saved results and displays them in the search result page

Your question shows no research whatsoever regarding the Magento standard search extension.